# FileStream using block not disposing of file properly when using CopyToAsync

Tags: c#, async-await, io

I have a situation where I need to asynchronously move a small list of files to another location on the network. I have the following method to do this, but it is occasionally throwing an IO Exception (cannot access the file x because it is being used by another process) when trying to delete the source file. I expected the using block to take care of disposing the FileStreams for me so am not sure what is going on.

```
public static async Task MoveFileAsync(string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
    {
        using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
        using (var destinationStream = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
        {
            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
        }

        File.Delete(sourceFile);
    }
```

I tried doing this with a File.Move in a Parallel.ForEach loop but found the above method was much quicker in my tests. Any pointers on what might be going on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My first thought is to place a try catch on File.Delete and keep retrying to see if the process that has the file lets it go eventually. Any chance the files on your network are in current production use? Like a scenario where some user goes to the folder and opens one of the files you're trying to copy?

Comment: I don't think disposing has anything to do with it. Being able to open a file for reading does not necessarily mean that it is not used by some other process as well. You are giving others access to read it by `FileShare.Read`, so probably you are taking advantage of the same share flags set on the file by the other process. I also would not retry deleting the file because we don't know when the file will be released and it can never happen as well. (open on someone's desktop?). I would just copy (already done here) and write information somewhere for a late deletion

Comment: Is it possibly that you are trying to move the same file twice? Also have you tried replacing the `CopyToAsync` with `CopyTo`, and placing the outer `using` block inside an awaited `Task.Run`, to see if the problem is related with the asynchronous nature of the operation?

Comment: It's happening in my test environment that only I use but you have just triggered a thought that it's probably McAfee doing a scan of the file.